# Mirror object along vertical axis in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, symmetry

When in Unity I want to symmetrically mirror a transform along the x axis, for many shapes this works fine:

```cs
reflection.localRotation = new Quaternion(
        original.localRotation.x * -1f,
        original.localRotation.y,
        original.localRotation.z,
        original.localRotation.w * -1f
        );

reflection.localPosition = new Vector3(
        original.localPosition.x * -1f,
        original.localPosition.y,
        original.localPosition.z
        );
```

But what would be the code for mirroring along the y axis? And what for mirror along the z axis? The positioning part is easy, but I'm wondering about the quaternion part. Thanks!

Comment: I gather you have already tried making the corresponding changes for the y/z-coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I tried all possible combinations. And while it did something, it never provided the wanted mirror plane.

Answer (score 1):

In 3d, you don't really mirror along an axis, but regarding a plane.

There is a [thread in the Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-mirror-a-euler-angle-or-rotation.90650/) about this. One of the solution proposes a way to rotate not just for specific axis-aligned planes, but for any mirror plane represented by a normal.

```
var objectQuat = transform.rotation;
var plane = GetMirrorPlane(); // choose yours here
var mirrorNormalQuat = new Quaternion(plane.x, plane.y, plane.z, 0);

var reflectedQuat = mirrorNormalQuat * objectQuat * mirrorNormalQuat;
transform.rotation = reflectedQuat;
```

Comment: Thank you. What kind of values would plane be? I've tried various Vector3's like 0f, 1f, 180f etc., but while they all rotate, none of the rotations is the one needed...

Comment: It is the normal to the plane you use as a mirror. (look on google if you don't know what the normal of a plane is). For instance if is (0, 0, 1) if your mirror is the x, y plane

Comment: Yes thanks, that's what I had tried, but none of the normal Vector3's I tried (e.g. (0, 0, 1) or (0, -1, 0) etc + various combos) resulted in the wanted rotation. What should the normal be for vertical mirroring anyways?

Comment: There is an infinity of possible vertical planes. All of them have a normal of the form (x, y, 0). Concerning the code, I don't know why it doesn't give you the proper result. Try reading the link I put in my answer to understand better how it works. Maybe your use case is a bit different

Answer (score 0):

modifying a quaternion by hand (treating it as an ordinary Vector4) as you do will not give you correct results. You'll be much better off modifying transform.eulerAngles (and as you want to mirror by a global axis I would imagine eulerAngles to be more apropriate than localEulerAngles but you could use either)

it still converts to a Quaternion internally but its just way easier to understand where you are in terms of rotation when using the Euler coordintate system